# ¿ Por qué está descolocado el formulario?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, formularios, textarea

Hola tengo este formulario puesto en columnas, en concreto `<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="form_container">` . Pero está descolocado, y no encuentro forma de ponerle de ancho total y las `label` y `textarea` queden colocadas a un ancho total.
Creo que el error vendrá de otros estilos, pues hasta que les cambien para que funcionaran en los dispositivos móviles, ( con ayuda de @Alvaro Montoro, del Cano, y algún otro compañero) tenía la apariencia de ancho total, tanto `textarea` como los `input`. cosa que tampoco tendría por qué, ya que esos estilos les aplique con estilos `@media`

```css
@media  only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) 
{
    #form_container {
      padding: 5%;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 9px solid #f2f2f2;            
      max-width: 520px;
      margin: auto;
    }

}
/* Añadido por Checho parrado  */
@media all and (max-width: 700px)
 { 
  #form_container{ 
    flex-direction: column; 
    padding: 10px; 
  } 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  #form_container{
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }

}
h1, p 
{
  text-align: center;
}

input, textarea , /*button*/
{
  width: 100% !important;
}    
textarea
{
  height: 200px !important;
}
button{
 background-color: #3bbec0 ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>formulario</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<section id="works">
  <class="home-section color-dark text-center bg-white">
   <div class="container marginbot-50">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div>
       <div class="animatedParent">
        <div class="section-heading text-center">
         <h2 class="h-bold animated bounceInDown">consultenos sin compromiso</h2>
         <div class="divider-header"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="text-center col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="informacion">

      <figure>
       <img src="../img/logo1.png" alt="Imagen de agrochema">
      </figure>
      <p>C/ bruselas,8</p>
      <p>05400 Arenas de San Pedro</p>
      <p>(Avila)</p>
     
      <p>arenas@gmail.com</p>
      <p>Puede seguir
       <a href="#punki">mi trabajo</a> en las redes sociales.</p>

     </div>

     <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="form_container">
      <div class="form-container">
       <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

       <h5>
        Contacte conmigo
       </h5>
       <form method="post" id="reused_form">
        <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Nombre...">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Correo electronico...">
        <label for="message">Mensage:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="Message" rows="10" maxlength="6000" required></textarea>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfMA0sUAAAAALFN5W-V06LOOeWEUf7T2hVlt5Yu"></div>
        <button class="button-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>

       </form>
       <div id="success_message" style="display:none">
        <h3>¡¡ El mensaje se envió con éxito...!!</h3>
        <p>Nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto. </p>
       </div>
       <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
        <h3>Error</h3>Lo sentimos, hubo un error al enviar su formulario.</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

 </section>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: no te interesa trabajaro con algun framework? para el manejo de diseño , o queires crear algo desde cero?

Comment: Amigo en donde lo estas probando? ya que veo tu col-xs-12 pero xs es en movil y en desktop esta con col-md-7 y por eso no ocupa todo el ancho.

Comment: no utilizo nada, bootstrap es lo único. Y para la pregunta de @Piero Pajares , estoy probando en ordenador. Gracias. Hice cambios por que en móviles se extendió el contenido, pero antes funcionaba perfectamente

Comment: De nada ! un abrazo! y bootstrap tambien es un framework.

Comment: lo que yo no entiendo para que poner dos class col en 12 y la otra en 7 o en 5?, si es 12 es 12 para todo ya que estas diciendo que con 12 ocuparas el 100% independiente si es xs, md, xl . E¿si lo pones en 12 toma el 100% independiente del dispositivo

Comment: si usas boostrap, entonces are el formulario y te lo dejare como respuesta , pero borrare esos css que creaste pero solo los que  ingresaste para afectar a los input y textarea.Otra cosa coloca una imagen para que mostrar como quieres que se vea , sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: La cosa es que deben ir la dirección a la izquierda y el formulario a la derecha, por eso la dirección  tiene 5, y el formulario 7, para que ocupe mas el formulario que la dirección. Gracias @SebastiánLagosYañez. Y luego tiene que valer para los dispositivos móviles ...

Answer (score 2):

Mira logre hacer lo siguiente con bootstrap 3 , la versión que tienes.

```css
@media  only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) 
{
    #form_container {
      padding: 5%;
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 9px solid #f2f2f2;            
      max-width: 520px;
      margin: auto;
    }

}
/* Añadido por Checho parrado  */
@media all and (max-width: 700px)
 { 
  #form_container{ 
    flex-direction: column; 
    padding: 10px; 
  } 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  #form_container{
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }

}
h1, p 
{
  text-align: center;
}

button{
 background-color: #3bbec0 ;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section id="works">
  <class="home-section color-dark text-center bg-white">
   <div class="container marginbot-50">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div>
       <div class="animatedParent">
        <div class="section-heading text-center">
         <h2 class="h-bold animated bounceInDown">consultenos sin compromiso</h2>
         <div class="divider-header"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="text-center col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="informacion">

      <figure>
       <img src="../img/logo1.png" alt="Imagen de agrochema">
      </figure>
      <p>C/ bruselas,8</p>
      <p>05400 Arenas de San Pedro</p>
      <p>(Avila)</p>
     
      <p>arenas@gmail.com</p>
      <p>Puede seguir
       <a href="#punki">mi trabajo</a> en las redes sociales.</p>

     </div>

     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="form_container">
      <div class="form-container">
       <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

       <h5>
        Contacte conmigo
       </h5>
       <form method="post" id="reused_form">
                <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Nombre...">
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" class="form-control" required maxlength="50" placeholder="Correo electronico...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Mensage:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="Message" class="form-control" rows="10" maxlength="6000" required></textarea>
                </div>
        <!--<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfMA0sUAAAAALFN5W-V06LOOeWEUf7T2hVlt5Yu"></div>-->
        <button class="button-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>

       </form>
       <div id="success_message" style="display:none">
        <h3>¡¡ El mensaje se envió con éxito...!!</h3>
        <p>Nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto. </p>
       </div>
       <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
        <h3>Error</h3>Lo sentimos, hubo un error al enviar su formulario.</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

 </section>
```

En el código anterior hice lo siguiente:

- Encerre los input y label en un div de clase `form-group`.
- Luego borre los css que manipulaban al textarea.
- Despues inserte las clases `form-control` a los input y al textarea.

> PD: las clases que mencioné arriba, son clases que vienen con
>   bootstrap 3 , por lo tanto no aparecen en el css que tienes tú.No se
>   si eso es lo que querias lograr , pero como no tengo tanta información
>   , solo hice lo que parecia.

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentar con lo que me has proporcionado, poner el formulario a la derecha de la dirección que es como estaba. Te cuento si lo consigo. y te la doy por buena @Sebastián Lagos Yañez